# Rotativa with Asp.net Core 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, rotativa

Please I need your help on this issue that I'm facing since 2 days now.
I'm using Rotativa.AspNetCore to export view in pdf with asp.net core 5, my code is working fine from visual studio 2019 but when I publish the app I'm getting this error:

> Error.  An error occurred while processing your request. Request ID:
> 00-4b8009f0978a2748b2467f7601bf7758-4639da00167d8849-00
>
> Development Mode Swapping to Development environment will display more
> detailed information about the  error that occurred. The Development
> environment shouldn't be enabled for deployed applications. It can
> result in displaying sensitive information from exceptions to end
> users. For local  debugging, enable the Development environment by
> setting the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT  environment variable to
> Development and restarting the app.

here is my code:

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> RibExport(string account)
  {
         rib_pdf rib = new rib_pdf();
         var pdf = new ViewAsPdf()
         {
            ViewName = "RibExport",
            FileName = "Rib.pdf",
            Model = rib,
            PageHeight = 200,
            PageOrientation = Rotativa.AspNetCore.Options.Orientation.Landscape,

        };
         return pdf
    }
```

I'm populating my rib model from my code for the contents.
I can't see any error from my logs files.
I do have:

1. wkhtmltoimage.exe
2. wkhtmltopdf.exe

from rotativa folder.

Comment: Hi @mxmissile, after enabling the debug for the production im having this error: An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
Exception: Error===>  Unable to create temporary file
Rotativa.AspNetCore.WkhtmlDriver.Convert(string wkhtmlPath, string switches, string html, string wkhtmlExe)

Comment: I dont know much about Rotativa but it looks like the app's identity doesnt have permission to create temporary files wherever Rotativa is trying to create them. Are you running under IIS?

Comment: @mxmissile yes under IIS

Comment: Make sure the Idenitity of the Application Pool you are using has access to the folder wherever Rotativa (or wkhtml?) does its work.

Comment: Hello @mxmissile i have created a user  logins with "IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool" and give him permission to the app folder in inetpub even from the Rotativa folder but no chance, same error.

Comment: You need to find out where Rotiva is creating temp files. Give permissions to that folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems is related with the IIS application pool identity permission issue. I suggest you could firstly set it as system to see if it could resolve this issue.

Like below:

[image]

If this has solved your issue, then you could run [process monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to see which permission is needed for accessing the temp folder, after checking it, you could modify the default identity provider IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool's permission to solve this issue

Comment: Hello @Brando, how are you, yes after changing for LocalSystem its works fine now i have put it back on ApplicationPoolIdentity , please how to find the APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool from the Process Monitor??? thanks so much

Comment: You could use it filter with the w3wp.exe by using the ApplicationPoolIdentity. It will show  which path it will face the error, then you could add the permission for that folder.

Comment: Hello @Brando, i think the issue is related to my local machine, as i do not have enough HDD memory, i have deployed the app in windows server and its working fine with ApplicationPoolIdentity. thanks.